# ibm-cos-sdk never returns in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I'm trying to use ibm-cos-sdk library to interact with an instance of Cloud Object Storage but I'm having some issues.

I got an example code from https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-js:

```
var AWS = require('ibm-cos-sdk');
var util = require('util');

var config = {
    endpoint: '<endpoint>',
    apiKeyId: '<api-key>',
    ibmAuthEndpoint: 'https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token',
    serviceInstanceId: '<resource-instance-id>',
};

var cos = new AWS.S3(config);

function doCreateBucket() {
    console.log('Creating bucket');
    return cos.createBucket({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket',
        CreateBucketConfiguration: {
          LocationConstraint: 'us-standard'
        },
    }).promise();
}

function doCreateObject() {
    console.log('Creating object');
    return cos.putObject({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket',
        Key: 'foo',
        Body: 'bar'
    }).promise();
}

function doDeleteObject() {
    console.log('Deleting object');
    return cos.deleteObject({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket',
        Key: 'foo'
    }).promise();
}

function doDeleteBucket() {
    console.log('Deleting bucket');
    return cos.deleteBucket({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket'
    }).promise();
}

doCreateBucket()
    .then(doCreateObject)
    .then(doDeleteObject)
    .then(doDeleteBucket)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Finished!');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error('An error occurred:');
        console.error(util.inspect(err));
    });
```

If you run this, you will notice that the process never ends: instead of printing the standard message 'Process finished with exit code 0', it keeps running also after printing 'Finished!' message.

Any idea?

Thanks,
FZ

Comment: @data_henrik I think that is just an example to show the cos operations. Have you tried `process.exit()`?

    `.then(function() {
        console.log('Finished!');
        process.exit()
    })`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in release 1.3.1.